# Flex uploader and details about flex

Tags: apache-flex, uploader

I making an uploader for 3rd party site, I don't want upload through my host (user upload to host, host upload to 3rd party site), it waste bandwidth so I decided choose flex, but I want know clearly about flex before I tried with it, can it handle http response after upload (redirect header, html response, json ...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly what you are looking for but there are a few flash based file uploaders that support cross domain (3rd-party) uploads:

fancyupload specifically addresses crossdomain support on their main page:
http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/1-0/

you do need to have a crossdomain.xml file on the third-party site there are instructions on how to do this:

http://forum.mootools.net/viewtopic.php?id=8312

and

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001590.html

they use the standard http multipart form post so as along as the receiving server can handle that they will work. On the client side provide javascript interfaces to get the results of the upload.

Answer (score 0):

yes, flex will handle the http response.

Comment: You should consider adding more depth to your answers. It helps keep SO a place for learning instead of a place for quick answers without context. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are after but you could try this **Flex/PHP uploader**. It has support for multi uploading and threaded simultaneous uploads:

http://bytearray.brixtonjunkies.com/2009/10/01/flex-multiple-file-uploader/